# How to measure number of packets sent by a node as a function of time ns2

Tags: plot, ns2

I'm writing a .tcl file for ns2 and I would like to get the number of packets sent by a node as a function of time and then plot it with xgraph.

I don't know how to do it.

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you descrive what you've tried so far ?

Comment: I've tried to modified the example (http://disi.unal.edu.co/profesores/jeortizt/Sim/Archivos/NS2/sim%20nivel1/sim5.txt) that calculates the bandwidth, but I don't know how to obtain packets sent by a node.